# Elasticsearch boost field don't give the expected result

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch with PHP and I'm tuning the results and I see that boosting the field "sessions" don't permit to really prioritize it because when i try to query "test paris" (paris can only be present in session field), The first and the second result don't contain "paris" in their session field the third yes.

I've tried to boost this field session but the result is that it reduces the number of results, not the order.

Here is my query:

```
$query = '
                    {
                    "from": 0,
                    "size": 100,
                    "min_score": 0.2,
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "query_string": {
                                "fields": 
                                [
                                    "sessions^3",
                                    "contenu^1",
                                    "objectifs^1",
                                    "intitule_stage^2",
                                    "mmp^1",
                                    "mots_cles^2" 
                                ],
                                "query": "' . $request . '~3"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "query_string": {
                                "fields": 
                                [
                                    "n_stage"
                                ],
                                "query": "*' . $filter_year . 'S"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }';
```

Thanks for your help ! ^_^

Comment: what's the elasticsearch version?

Comment: it's the version 6. I see that compared to version 2.4 (the first version I used to devellop) adding serching terms is increasing the result number instead of the version 2.4

Comment: Same result with 5.4 version (I know I should have install the stable version first but that don't change anything).